# Me sale dice que range1.push no es una función, es como una especie de prueba, podrían intentar resolverlo?

Tags: javascript

Me sale ese error y no he podido avanzar, es como una especie de prueba, pero la verdad me quedo muy dificil, no conozco mucho del tema, pero lo estoy intentado, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

```
'use strict';

module.exports.multiplyRange = (event, context, callback) => {

    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end;

    // Fix code below
    var range1 = [0];
    for (var i = start; 1 <= end; i++) {
        range1 = range1.push(i);
    }

    let multiply = (a, b) => a + b;
    var result = l.reduce(multiply);

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: {
            result: result,
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: Aparte del problema con el iterador, estás asignando el resultado de `range1.push` en la primera iteración a la variable `range1`. Por lo tanto en la siguiente iteración la variable `range1` ya no es un Array y por lo tanto `push` no está definida.

Comment: ¿A qué te referís con _es como una especie de prueba_?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código tienes

```
var range1 = [0];
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) { // aquí debería ser i <= end en lugar de 1 <=end
    range1 = range1.push(i);
}
```

Según la documentación de [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.

`range1.push(i)` devuelve la nueva longitud del arreglo.

El mensaje de error es por lo siguiente:

Primero declaras `range1` como un arreglo que ya contiene el elemento 0. Luego, cuando entras al ciclo `for`, en la primera iteración, realizas una re-asignación de la variable `range1` al entero `2`, porque `Array.push()` devuelve un entero. Entonces, en la siguiente iteración falla porque `range1` **ya no es un array, es un entero**. De ahí el mensaje que *range push no es una función*.

Debería funcionar sólo removiendo la reasignación de la variable dentro del ciclo for. Así

```
const start =1;
const end = 10;

var range1 = [0];
for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    range1.push(i); // eliminas el 'range1 ='
}
console.log(range1) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
'use strict';

module.exports.multiplyRange = (event, context, callback) => {

    var start = event.start;
    var end = event.end;

    // Fix code below
    var range = [];
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }
    
    let multiply = (a, b) => a * b;
    var result = range.reduce(multiply);

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', // Required for CORS support to work
        },
        body: {
            result: result,
        },
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.